# ActionBarSherlock and pre 3.0 Android devices

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, actionbarsherlock

I'm implementing the SherlockActionBar for an Android application, but I wanna maintain a backward compatibility with pre Honeycomb devices.

This is the sample code:

```
package com.sherlockbar.example;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity;

public class SherlockExampleActivity extends SherlockActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {
    private TextView mSelected;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.tab_navigation);
        mSelected = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);

        getSupportActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
            ActionBar.Tab tab = getSupportActionBar().newTab();
            tab.setText("Tab " + i);
            tab.setTabListener(this);
            getSupportActionBar().addTab(tab);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction transaction) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction transaction) {
        mSelected.setText("Selected: " + tab.getText());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction transaction) {
    }
}
```

For 4.0 devices this works perfect, but for Honeycomb it doesn't work -I get the following error:

> E/AndroidRuntime(2363): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   You must use Theme.Sherlock, Theme.Sherlock.Light,
>   Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar, or a derivative.

In the manifest I tried to establish that them but it's not in the suggested list, plus if I write it, I still get the error.

How do I set the bar up for Honeycomb devices please?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Post your manifest where you have one of the Sherlock themes set up.

Comment: @CommonsWare this is what I have: <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock" >

Comment: You should not be getting that error any more with that manifest. Here is a small sample project using ActionBarSherlock: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ActionBar/ActionBarDemo  Note that you will need to attach your own copy of ABS as a library project.

Comment: I attached the ABS project downloaded from the webpage as a library, but still the same..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you compiling against 4.0? You need to target the Android 4.0 sdk in order for it to compile correctly (even if you're running on < 4.0).

Comment: yes, this is what I have: <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="4"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

Comment: @noloman: That has nothing to do with the suggestion. You need to have your project's *build target* set to Android 4.0+. For example, in Eclipse, you set your project's build target via Project > Properties > Android.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have set up ActionBarSherlock as a library project. Until you do that, your project won't be able to access resources in ABS